# File upload with AJAX using Backbone and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I need to send a file and other form data, to an ASP.NET MVC Controller through AJAX, while leveraging Backbone.

My only certainty so far is that I need to handle Backbone's "sync" function, where I will $.post the file and form data to the controller.

My question is - How could I get the file contents through jQuery? Thank you.

Comment: what's wrong with Ajax.BeginForm()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two choices - either use HTML5 File API or not. We had users running IE9, so we had to discard HTML5 File API. Then, we used jQuery file upload plugin to upload the files (and send data) to the controller.